# How To Keep Close Button for Windows 10 Always Highlighted Via Regedit

Tags: windows, themes, regedit

I would like to keep it so the close button for Windows is permanently red colored, even when it's not hovered like so:

Is there any way to do this without downloading third party window manager applications? Thank you!

I am trying to make windows 10 more MetroUI (8.1) like without installing external third party programs that will run in the background. [This is what i want the result to be like, without hovering over the button itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Wzp.png)